# Is it allowed to leave a salah midway (for any reason like breaking wudu) and pray all over again afterwards?

Tags: salat

I've been seeing this videos where people are dying but instead of providing instant help they're trying to finish the salah. What does hadith says?

Is it completely forbidden to stop praying in the midway.

https://youtu.be/ueD76v4Fj68 ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is permissible to break salah when there is a valid reason.

Breaking wudu also breaks salah automatically. So you have to leave and you do not have a choice in this matter. A relevant hadith could be:

> إذا أحدث أدكم في صلاته فليأخذ بأنفه ثم لينصرف
>
> If any of you breaks wind during prayer he should hold his nose* and withdraw.
>
> {* pretend to have a nosebleed so you are not held back by embarrasment}
>
> <sup>— [Abu Dawud](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:1114)</sup>

There are cases where it is permitted or even obligatory to intentionally break Salah. This happens when the purpose of breaking salah is to protect your own or someone else's life or property. Examples include:

- To save someone's life. For example when someone calls for help, or when they are drowning or on fire or about to fall from a height, or being attacked by someone, or when an infant is about to harm himself. Or when you see a snake or scorpion, see [hadith](https://sunnah.com/abudawud:921).
- To save someone's property. For example when a horse is running away, or cattle are being attacked by a wolf, or when a thief is taking something, or when something is about to get burnt in a fire, or even if food that is being cooked is about to get burnt.

If someone has a heart attack during the congregational prayer then at least one person should break off and tend to patient and maybe call an ambulance. He can always repeat the prayer later.

**Ref:** [الفقه الإسلامي وأدلته](https://shamela.ws/book/384/1010)